# How to assigne a new column after groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to groupby my data and create a new column assignment.

Given the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2'], 'col2': [1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6]})
df['col3']=df[['col1','col2']].groupby('col1').rolling(2).mean().reset_index()

Expected output = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2'], 'col2': [1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6], 'col3': [NAN, 1.5, 2.5, NAN, 4.5, 5.5]})
```

However, this does not work. Is there an straightforward way to do it?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Revised and included the expected output

Comment: Only the assignment part does not work. Worst case scenario I can merge with the original dataframe but I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `groupby`, `apply` and `assign`:

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index = False).apply(lambda g: g.assign(col3 = g['col2'].rolling(2).mean())).reset_index(drop = True)
```

output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0   x1     1   NaN
1   x1     2   1.5
2   x1     3   2.5
3   x2     4   NaN
4   x2     5   4.5
5   x2     6   5.5
```